# "Verify EAR Libraries" error with linked resources

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, project, relative-path

We have an Eclipse project that needs access to `appserv-rt.jar` from a local Glassfish installation. Since this jar has to be *in* a working Glassfish installation and that installation can be on different places on developers workstations, I introduced a Linked Resource and added the library via the Linked Resource.

This works fine, but now when Eclipse starts the workspace I'm greeted by these errors:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Verify EAR Libraries".
An internal error occurred during: "Verify Web App Libraries".
```

Is this simply an Eclipse bug or is there a better way to solve this in Eclipse? I don't want to simply disable all verifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similiar problem with my EAR libs of my application. What worked for me is removing the temporary files (build folder) including the eclipse settings (.settings, .classpath, .project) and rebuilding the application.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove jre libraries in the build path of project and then added jre libraries again..it worked for me. Try it may this resolve your problem